# How to make the list move more to the left

Tags: html, css

I have this list:

[image: list]

How can I make the list be in line with the top bar, ie. the total width of the list will be 960px just like the top bar?

I don't understand why it isn't working. The size of each of the squares is 159px + 1px for margin, and yet they make a profit from the right that I didn't define.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo_bg {
  width: 65px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #146ca6;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: "Bahnschrift";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #363427;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #363427;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 159px;
  height: 100px;
}

#games {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width:959px) {
  #container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #logo_bg {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
  }
  li {
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>2TheGames</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <div id="logo_bg">2Tg</div>
    </header>

    <article id="games">
      <ul>
        <li><a>1</a></li>
        <li><a>2</a></li>
        <li><a>3</a></li>
        <li><a>4</a></li>
        <li><a>5</a></li>
        <li><a>6</a></li>

      </ul>
    </article>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS. You may also want to edit your question so that the image hyperlink is labeled more clearly.

Comment: i add sorry and ty

Comment: <ul style="margin:0;padding:0">

Comment: Set ul padding to 0

Comment: Thanks everyone it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo_bg {
  width: 65px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #146ca6;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: "Bahnschrift";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #363427;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #363427;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 159px;
  height: 100px;
}

#games {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width:959px) {
  #container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #logo_bg {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
  }
  li {
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have found an answer that works for you - please select it as the accepted answer, so the person who helped you can be credited for their help.